# Is the limit point of this sequence unique?

Tags: real-analysis

To my opinion, this is a very interesting problem. I have this problem when I was reading a recent paper.

For simplicity, we will consider $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that we have a sequence $\{{\bf x}_k\}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\,\|{\bf x}_k-{\bf x}_{k-1}\|<\infty$. It is trivial to see that $\{{\bf x}_k\}$ is bounded and $\|{\bf x}_k-{\bf x}_{k-1}\|\rightarrow0$. Therefore, this sequence must have a limit point.

My question is:

1: Is the limit point unique?

2: Is this sequence converge?

I thought the limit point was not unique and I constructed several counter examples. But, I finally found that my counter examples violated the boundedness of the difference sum. Therefore, I conjecture if we can make more from the condition. Thanks.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to drop the square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon >0$ and let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $\sum_{k=N}^\infty \|x_k-x_{k-1}\|<\epsilon$. Then for $m>n\geq N$ we have by the triangle inequality $$\|x_m-x_n\|\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\|x_k-x_{k-1}\|<\epsilon.$$ Therefore the sequence is Cauchy, and I presume you know what to say from here.

Comment: Great. I'd better pick up a book and review some basics.

Answer (score 2):

Try $n=1$, with $x_n = \sum_{j=1}^n 1/j$.  The sequence is **not** bounded and does not converge.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Please see my edit.